# Como faço para abrir um Service a partir de um BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou criando uma aplicação que intercepta um sms via `BroadcastReceiver`, mais a partir disso quero que ao receber esse sms via `broadcast` abra um `service`. provavelmente isso é feito via `Intent` mais não conseguir fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa iniciar o serviço no onReceive da classe que implementa o BroadcastReceiver:

```
import meu.pacote.com.o.servico.MinhaClasseServico;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

public class MeuBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MinhaClasseServico.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```